# Delete "URL:" prefix in biblatex online entries? include date visited?

Tags: biblatex, urls

The source below produces with `biblatex`'s numeric style the prefix "URL:" to the URL of an `online` type bibliography entry:

[image: biblatex online entry with unwanted "URL:" prefix]

1. What file(s) need to be modified so as to eliminate that "URL:" prefix?
   I've searched through `numeric.bbx`, `standard.bbx`, and `biblatex.sty` but not been able to find any specific place where that prefix is created.
2. Is there a field, style mod, or other means for including the online item's date of access other than as I've done it with the `addendum` field?  I'm aware that `english.lbx`, in its `\DeclareBibliographyStrings` section, does define a `dateseen`, but where and how does one use it?

The source:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

 \begin{filecontents}{refs.bib}
@online{mathworld:Topology,
  author = {Wikipedia},
  title  = {BibTeX---{W}ikipedia{,} The Free Encyclopedia},
  year   = {2016},
  Addendum   = {[accessed 27-Oct-2016]},
  url    = {https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BibTeX}
  }
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=numeric]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{refs.bib}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to look in `biblatex.def` and `english.lbx` to deal with the 'format' of how URLs are defined. The `.lbx` files contain the bibliography strings such as 'visited on' (the original definition for the field `urldate`).

This question is a good example of why loading `babel` or `polyglossia` is strongly recommended regardless of whether your document is monolingual or not.... (And, I should add, `csquotes`!)

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@online{mathworld:Topology,
  author = {Wikipedia},
  title  = {BibTeX---{Wikipedia}, The Free Encyclopedia},
  year   = {2016},
  xxxAddendum   = {[accessed 27-Oct-2016]},
  urldate = {2016-10-27},
  url    = {https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BibTeX}
  }
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[strict]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=numeric]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

% Original definitions in biblatex.def
% \DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\mkbibacro{URL}\addcolon\space\url{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\url{#1}}
% \DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\mkbibparens{\bibstring{urlseen}\space#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\mkbibbrackets{\bibstring{urlseen}\space#1}}

% Original definition in english.lbx:
% urlseen =    {{visited on}{visited on}},
\DefineBibliographyStrings{american}{%
  urlseen =    {accessed},
}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is it possible to redefine `uirlseen` *without* loading `babel`? And , is `csquotes` needed in either case?

Comment: OK, I see that if we use `\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{url seen = {accessed}}` then `babel` is not needed.

Comment: Yes, but why not load it? Without them, you will not get "American style punctuation," but the so-called "British sort of punctuation", though you'll note that double quotation marks are still used rather than 'inverted commas'.

Comment: You will also (possibly) be using British hyphenation and not American hyphenation by default. (Not that I'm bashing it! -- As a Canadian, that'd be fine with me, but you may have a different opinion.)

Comment: Alas, in my real project (with multiple files that are input into the preamble and a nested structure with a couple dozen files for the main matter and back matter): loading `babel` causes indexing to fail. This is for reasons I do not yet understand and cannot yet isolate. It seems to have something to do with having the index page header style show the first & last entries on the particular page. So I'm going to temporarily "unaccept" the answer in the hope that somebody will point me in the right direction.

Comment: I don't understand. You noted that you can use `english` in \DefineBibliographyStrings`; why doesn't that work now? (All I was pointing out was that, if you do not load `babel`, there may be other consequences -- mainly with respect to hyphenation. But that is not, strictly speaking, part of the problem here.)

Comment: Yes, `english` in `\DefineBibliographyStrings` works OK. But `american`, instead, with `babel` loaded, causes trouble in the actual document (as opposed to the minimal example I posted).

Comment: @murray -- It's hard to know what to suggest for `.tex` files I haven't seen. But, as a generalization, I'd say that a `.tex` file that can't handle `babel` being loaded may well deserve some serious scrutiny. There may actually be some serious problems with the file(s)...