# Biblatex - disable bib entry type "@online" URL output but print accessed date

Tags: biblatex

I have been trying to modify the `biblatex.def` commands to output `@Online` bib entries like the following (using Wikipedia as an example):

> Wikipedia. *Wikipedia the Wikipedia*. 2022. Accessed: 06/07/2022.

My style modifications achieved up until 2022, but I cannot seem to get the combination correct for the accessed date and the `urldate` is not being printed as is. I am using the `numeric`/`numeric-comp` styles depending on the article type. I am using a macro to hyperlink all entries to either their DOI (`@Article`) or URL (`@Online`) with a prenote stating this so I do not need the actual URL outputting into the bibliography entry.

After trying the solutions [in this answer by jon](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/336321/273733), I still cannot get the `urldate` to output, let alone change the format of it. My efforts using `\DeclareFieldFormat[online]{url}{}` did not work nor editing the:

```
\newbibmacro*{url+urldate}{%
  \usebibmacro{url}%
  \iffieldundef{urlyear}
    {}
    {\setunit*{\addspace}%
     \usebibmacro{urldate}}}

\newbibmacro*{url}{\printfield{url}}
```

to:

```
\renewbibmacro*{url+urldate}{%
    \setunit*{\addspace}%
    \usebibmacro{urldate}}

\renewbibmacro*{url}{}
```

Does anyone know how I can print the accessed date without the URL for `@Online` bib entries in the `numeric`/`numeric-comp` styles please?

MWE:

```
\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@Online{Wiki,
  author  = {Wikipedia},
  title   = {Wikipedia the Wikipedia},
  url     = {https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page},
  urldate = {06/07/2022},
  year    = {2022},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{test.bib}

% Original definition in english.lbx:
% urlseen =    {{visited on}{visited on}},
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  urlseen =    {Accessed:},
}

\begin{document}
\cite{Wiki}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

How it currently looks:

[image]

Comment: your input of the date is wrong. You must use ISO, so `urldate = {2022-07-06},`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must input the date in ISO format.

```
\begin{filecontents}[force]{testurl.bib}
@Online{Wiki,
  author  = {Wikipedia},
  title   = {Wikipedia the Wikipedia},
  url     = {https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page},
  urldate = {2022-06-07},
  year    = {2022},
}
\end{filecontents}



\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric]{biblatex}

\renewbibmacro*{url+urldate}{%
    \setunit*{\addspace}%
    \usebibmacro{urldate}}
    
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{{\bibstring{urlseen}\space#1}}    

\addbibresource{testurl.bib}

% Original definition in english.lbx:
% urlseen =    {{visited on}{visited on}},
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  urlseen =    {Accessed:},
}

\begin{document}
\cite{Wiki}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]